# Unable to download dataset from Power BI service

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset sitting in our PBI service (premium). The are 2 DirectQuery tables in the dataset. When I attempt to download the dataset as a PBIX file, I get the error shown below:

[image]

Anyone have any idea why I cannot download this dataset?

Comment: Are you the owner of this Data Set?

Comment: Yes, I uploaded it and then attempted to download it. However, if this were a permissions error, wouldn't the error state that?

Comment: Have you tried to turn off the large dataset option? 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-large-models#enable-large-models

Comment: have you made edits to the dataset via XMLA or enabled incremental refresh?

Comment: No to both of your questions

Comment: Better raise a ticket nothing to worry on the Data set side. Maybe a server issue.

Comment: It could be a server side issue because the error code is 500.